# What's the story behind the item Celty is looking for?

Tags: durarara

I know Izaya

> has her legitimate head, but how'd she lose it in the first place? She's also a Dullahan, so I don't understand why she even wants her head back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Shinra's father stole Celty's head when she was asleep, and gave it to Yagiri Pharmaceuticals. 
>  Celty wants her head back because it houses her memories.